# Generate random numbers in array and count the average, max, min, sum

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers, generator

This code is supposed to generate 30 random numbers, 0-100, and print the average, max value, and the min value. But it has logical errors and I cant help but think I've made a stupid mistake.

****code is supposed to generate 30 numbers from 0-100, and display mean, max, and min****

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 30

int generateRandom(void); 

int main(void)
{

    int points[SIZE], i, sum, max, min, num; 
    double average; 

    srand(time(NULL));                      /*Seed random number generator*/

    num = generateRandom();                 /*Genrate the random numbers*/

    printf("num = %d\n", num);              /*Print the random numbers*/

    sum = 0; 
    for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)             /*Find the average*/
    {
        sum += points[i]; 
        average = sum / SIZE; 
    }
    printf("Average = %f", average);        /*Print the average*/


    max = points[0];                        /*initialize the max to 0*/
    for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)             /*find the min*/
    {
        if (points[i] > max)
        {
            max = points[i]; 
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum = %d\n", max);          /*print the maximum number*/

    min = points[0];                        /*initialize the min*/
    for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)             /*Find the min*/
    {
        if (points[i] < min)
        {
            min = points[i]; 
        }
    }
    printf("Minimum = %d\n", min);          /*Print the minimum number*/


    return 0; 

}

int generateRandom(void)
{
    int random; 

    random = rand() % 101; 

    return random;
}
```

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "How do I fix logic errors". The first step is to understand where the errors are. The best tool to use for that is a debugger. A debugger will allow you to trace the execution of the program and examine its state as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You generate just one random number, which you store in `num`. Then your code behaves as if it had 30 random numbers stored in `points`. But it never makes this happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 30

int generateRandom(void);

int main(void)
{

    int points[SIZE],i,sum,max,min,num;
    double average;

    srand(time(NULL));                             

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        points[i] = generateRandom();
    }

    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum += points[i];
    }
    average = (sum * 1.0) / SIZE;   /*you need double here*/
    printf("Average = %f\n",average);      


    max = points[0];                       
    for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)            
    {
        if(points[i] > max)
        {
            max = points[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum = %d\n",max);     

    min = points[0];                     
    for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)            
    {
        if(points[i] < min)
        {
            min = points[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Minimum = %d\n",min); 

    return 0;
}

int generateRandom(void)
{
    int random;

    random = rand() % 101;

    return random;
}
```